# Lint: "Newer Library Versions Available" when using variables

Tags: android, groovy, dependencies, android-lint, android-studio-3.0

I have a project with 3 sub-projects. I want the 3 sub-projects to use the same dependencies versions so I factored all the versions in the root `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
ext.versions = [
        supportLibVersion: '26.1.0',
        playServicesVersion: '11.2.2',
        retrofitVersion: '2.1.0',
        retrofitConverterGsonVersion: '2.1.0',
        retrofitRxjava2AdapterVersion: '1.0.0',
        rxjava2Version: '2.0.5',
        rxandroidVersion: '2.0.1',
        timberVersion: '4.5.1',
        ...
]
}
```

Now lint doesn't highlight new libraries available anymore. It somehow still works for the supportLibs but not for the other ones.

Any chance I can have this working again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an exact answer to the question. I had the same concerns some time ago (had declared global vars and referred to them from `build.gradle` files).

I've found [gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) library, which resolved my concerns.

It will prompt with detailed info after `./gradlew dependencyUpdates`

[image]

Comment: Nice, it looks like it also finds more upgrades than lint too. Thanks.

Comment: Also, it looks like it works with android gradle plugin 3.0.0-beta6

Comment: @mbonnin, yep it does, I forgot to add `google()` as a repository source. Updating the answer.

Comment: With Gradle `4.6` and Gradle plugin `3.2.1` I'm getting error `Resolving configuration 'androidTestAnnotationProcessorCopy' directly is not allowed`. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, go to the `Analyze` menu and choose `Run Inspection by Name` -> `Newer Library Versions Available`. Choose `Whole Project` and wait for your results.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I have found (AS 3.6.3) is to open the project structure with Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S where there is a Suggestions tab:

[image]