# What is the correct way to move gradle dependency versions to a variable?

Tags: android, gradle

In order to maintain the version numbers of my gradle dependencies, I chose the below pattern.

In my project level `build.gradle` I added:

```
ext.versions = [
            'kotlin_version'   : '1.2.30',
            'dagger'           : '2.16'
]
```

And in my app module's `build.gradle` I added:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${versions.dagger}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${versions.dagger}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${versions.dagger}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${versions.dagger}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${versions.dagger}"
```

But my problem is after doing this, I lost the lint warnings of "***Newer Library versions available***".

**What is the correct way to do this without missing the lint checks?**

Note: I have also tried other ways like moving these versions to gradle.properties file (for global variables).

I am looking for a solution inside Android Studio. There is one solution which I already found:

`Analyze -> Run Inspection by name... -> Type "Newer Library Versions Available"`

But my concern is, it is easy to miss on updates until we run some or the other script. That is why I am trying to **find a way where dependency versions can be put in a variable and get lint warning for new updates**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lint: "Newer Library Versions Available" when using variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295985/lint-newer-library-versions-available-when-using-variables)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46296198/2053763

There is a link to a gradle plugin which can check for dependency updates.

Android Studio 3.1.2 offers some lint checks while using version variables, but still misses some of the updates. See image below:

[image]

Comment: I am looking for a solution inside Android studio rather than some plugin or script. Even I am using AS 3.1.2 and I never got an update warning! Interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this and it's really useful. Finally I can see warnings again. The plugin in the mentioned answer is not working for me with Gradle 4.6 and Gradle plugin 3.2.1 - I'm getting error `Resolving configuration 'androidTestAnnotationProcessorCopy' directly is not allowed.`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract dependencies versions into variables stored in a separate Gradle file and then check and update them from the Project Structure (ctrl+alt+shift+S) (screenshot from Android Studio 3.6.3):

[image]